# Play audio on Apple Watch without bluetooth

Tags: watchos-2

Has anyone been able to successfully do this yet? I don't want a media player to pop up, or play the sound through bluetooth, just have a button that plays an audio file.

I setup the WKAudioFilePlayer like the apple website says, but it doesn't "play through the speaker if no bluetooth is detected". if you press the button it immediately asked to connect to bluetooth and thats the only option. anyone figure this out?